# Set Kendo DDL value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I want to update a MVC Kendo DropDownList using Ajax. The display is working, when I call the Ajax function I can see the value being selected in the DDL. But when I submit my page the DDL value is null. If I select a value manually it's working.

My view looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div class="col-md-10">
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.typeID)
  .Name("typeID")
  .DataTextField("name")
  .DataValueField("ID")
  .OptionLabel(" ")
  .Value(Model.typeID.ToString())
  .DataSource(d => d.Read("_ListOfTypes", "User"))
  )
</div>
}
```

My script looks like:

```
function searchUser(_e)
{
 $.ajax({
 url: "../../Account/_getUserInfo?_name=" + $("#username").val(),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (_data) {
        $("#name").val(_data.name).change();
        $("#typeID").data('kendoDropDownList').text(_data.type);
    }
  });
}
```

If I commit my page the 'typeID' will be null. At this point I need to click the DDL, select the selected value then commit to make it works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set Kendo Dropdown with `text` property which is just replacing visible text and doesn't replace the value.

Remove `$("#typeID").data('kendoDropDownList').text(_data.type);` and try following code.

```
var dropdownlist = $("#typeID").data("kendoDropDownList");

dropdownlist.select(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.value === _data.type; 
});

// Or Try dropdownlist.select(_data.type);
```

I am not sure what's inside the _data so I've assumed _data.type should hold the Id of the Type which you'd like to select.

Also, please check different ways to set the Kendo Dropdown value.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/select